# Error occured while playing videos

Tags: updates

Please help me.i download the offline videos from you tube successful but when i want to play the video the error occured like there was problem while playing touch to retry.

Answer (score -2):

Did you use tubemate?

Tubemate is incredibly easy to use and i never had any problem playing the videos downloaded using it.

Just google "tubemate apk" and install it and then go to any browser and browse youtube, once you have done selecting a particular video just copy the url of that video and paste it in tubemate url section which is located on a slider on the left and then click the green arrow that appears on the toolbar and voila youre done. :)